# Definir background LinearLayout a partir de variavel String

Tags: android, background, drawable

Tenho uma função que recebe um número(no formato String) como parâmetro e verifica se ele está entre os números de 1 a 5. Aqui vai a função:

```
if (fundo.equals("1") || fundo.equals("2") || fundo.equals("3") || fundo.equals("4") || fundo.equals("5"))
{
    fundo = "bg_" + fundo;
    fundoTopo.setBackground(R.drawable. <-- Queria colocar a variavel aqui);
}
```

Mas isso gera um erro pois o formato recebido é String, e o formato necessário é Drawable, como resolver isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível obter o `id` de um *drawable* assim:

```
int id = context.getResources()
                .getIdentifier(fundo, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
```

Obtido o `id` use [setBackgroundResource()](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource%28int%29):

```
fundoTopo.setBackgroundResource(id);
```

Tudo junto será assim:

```
if (fundo.equals("1") || fundo.equals("2") || fundo.equals("3") || fundo.equals("4") || fundo.equals("5"))
{
    fundo = "bg_" + fundo;
    int id = context.getResources()
                    .getIdentifier(fundo, "drawable", context.getPackageName()); 
    fundoTopo.setBackgroundResource(id);
}
```

Comment: Valeu funcionou certinho.